# How do I generate an Oracle SQL statement , where each column would need its own separate query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I need to use separate queries to fill in the individual columns :

It would look Something like this for each column

```
select PERFORMED_DATE from HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY where 
    REG_REQUEST_ID IN ('261507') AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ASD' 
AS "Security"
UNION
select PERFORMED_DATE from HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY where 
    REG_REQUEST_ID IN ('261507') AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'OTZ' 
AS "Training"
UNION
select PERFORMED_DATE from HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY where 
    REG_REQUEST_ID IN ('261507') AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ARA' 
AS "Responsibility"
```

The only thing changing in each column is the `ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE`.

I know that this syntax would not work. Is there a syntax to do this?

My query would grab different data from a specific table, for each different column.
My database output screenshot, which is for this query :

`SELECT * FROM HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY where REG_REQUEST_ID IN ('262050') AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ASD' AND ROWNUM < 2` :
[image]

The user-spreadsheet looks like this :
So columns "Responsibility" / "Supervisor" would each correspond to their own unique value for the column `ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE` ( these called "UPA request statuses" - one of SBT, WSP, ASP, WRA, ARA, WTV, ATV ... etc ) :

[image]
thanks !

Comment: `where REG_REQUEST_ID = '261507' AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE IN ('ASD', 'OTZ', 'ARA')`. Btw: if `REG_REQUEST_ID` is a number you shouldn't compare it to a string.

Comment: Could you provide sample data and expected output, please? I suspect you're after a pivot, but if there are two rows with the activity_result_code = 'ASD' with different dates, what would you expect the output to be? The highest date? Both dates? If the latter, how would you expect that to be displayed? etc etc

Comment: @Boneist - I added screenshots, not sure if that what you meant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to display information from different rows in the same row of the result set. The standard answer is a join, even if we join the same table:

```
select 
  securityRow.REQ_REQUEST_ID, 
  securityRow.PERFORMED_DATE as securityDate, 
  trainingRow.PERFORMED_DATE as trainingDate, 
  responsibilityRow.PERFORMED_DATE as responsibilityDate
from HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY securityRow
join HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY trainingRow on trainingRow.REG_REQUEST_ID = securityRow.REG_REQUEST_ID
join HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY responsibilityRow on responsibilityRow.REQ_REQUEST_ID = securityRow.REG_REQUEST_ID
where securityRow.ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ASD' 
  and trainingRow.ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'OTZ' 
  and responsibilityRow.ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 'ARA'
```

This assumes that there is exactly one row matching for each REQ_REQUEST_ID and ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE. Otherwise, if there is at most one, you'll want to use outer joins as necessary. If there are several rows, you must restrict the result set to the one you want to use.

Comment: Ah , yes the outer joins .  i do need to use that, bec. I'm getting huge huge data

Comment: Erm, outer joins won't make the data smaller. I have edited to make it clearer when they would be used.

Answer (score 1):

You say "For each different column" but there are not different columns. Only different selections on the `Activity_result_code`.

They syntax you have now, with the exception of the table aliases, would work fine, it's just completely unnecessary. The query you have written could also be written as:

```
select PERFORMED_DATE 
from HHS_UMX_RESP_ACTIVITY 
where REG_REQUEST_ID = '261507' AND ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE IN ('ASD','OTZ','ARA'); 
GROUP BY PERFORMED_DATE
```

Comment: Hi , I added in more information,   is your query still applicable in my case